# Maximum of minimums

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Suppose $v_1,\ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are vector with all coordinates non-negative. How to explicitly calculate:
$$ \max_{x\geqslant 0, ||x||_1=1} \min_{1\leqslant i \leqslant k} <x,v_i>$$

Remark1: $x\geqslant 0$ means that all all coordinates of $x$ are non-negative and $||x||_1=1$ means that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1$.

Remark2: In terms of game theory, my problem is to calculate the value of a game with the 'row' and 'column' player and a matrix with non-negative entries.

Comment: My intuition tells that the maximum is attained at a nonnegative eigenvector of the matrix $V=(v_1|\cdots |v_k)$. Moreover, this looks a lot like a Collatz-Wielandt ratio. In particular, if $V$ has a positive eigenvector $x^*$, then, by the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, the associated eigenvalue is $\rho(V)$ (the spectral radius) and the collatz-Wielandt ratio imply that $$\max_{x\geq 0,\|x\|=1}\min_{x_i\neq 0}\frac{\langle x,v_i\rangle}{x_i}=\rho(V)=\min_{x\geq 0,\|x\|=1}\max_{x_i\neq 0}\frac{\langle x,v_i\rangle}{x_i}=\rho(V)\frac{\langle x^*,v_j\rangle}{x^*_j} \qquad \forall j.$$

Comment: This seems very helpful. Can you please provide me some reference about Collatz–Wielandt formula? Also, as far as I could check, it doesn't take in the account that $x$ goes over the non-negative unit vectors with respect to 1-norm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be written more concisely in the form

$$\max_{x \in \mathcal X}\min_{y \in \mathcal Y}\langle y, Ax\rangle,$$
where $A = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\ldots\\v_k\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{k \times n}$, $\mathcal X := \{x \in \mathbb R^n | x \ge 0, \|x\|_1 \le 1\}$ and $\mathcal Y := \Delta_k$, the $k$-simplex. Your problem is thus to compute Nash-equilibrium for a two-player matrix game with payoff matrix $A$, and strategy profiles $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$. This can be done using a linear-programming solver, or more advanced methods of Nesterov (excessive-gap technique, etc.), Chambolle-Pock, etc. In these latter cases, note that there are linear time algorithms due to Duchi, Condat, etc., for pojection onto either of the strategy profiles.

**N.B.:** $\min_{1 \le i \le k}z_k = \min_{y \in \Delta_m}\langle y, z \rangle$.